# Objective-C Camera Crop Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a routine that I use to trigger the camera to take a photo.  After the camera takes the photo the user is then given an option to crop the image by default before the delegate passes me back the `UIImage`.  Is there any way that I can pass in a dynamic `CGRect` to make this default crop area a specific size?  One thing I should mention is that the application is a landscape iPad application.

Here is a code sample:

```
-(void)triggerCamera:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    camera.delegate = self;
    camera.allowsEditing = YES;
    camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    //pass in some sort of CGRect ??
    [self presentViewController:camera animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {

    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //process my image further
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't set crop size. I was dealing with same problem over 2 years ago and I got stuck with creating my own viewController for cropping image.

Comment: I was afraid of this.  I was hoping I could kill 2 birds with one stone so I do not have to resize/crop the image after it is returned from the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a look at [GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker) on GitHub. This project hasn't had much activity in the past few months (maybe more), but could be worth a shot. It even comes with an option to have a resizable crop area. I have not tried it myself, but the implementation looks to be pretty simple:

```
self.imagePicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(320, 90);
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: OK, will check it out.  Thanks Corey!

Comment: I tried this project and was unable to get the desired result.  I am wanting to be able to get the crop size after I take the photo to be dynamic.  One this I should have mentioned is that my application is a landscape only, iPad application.  I will edit my question for clarity.